# Insert Sales Order by graph in Acumatica

Tags: cloud, erp, acumatica

I am trying to insert sales order through graph 
My code is work but it can't insert into database
This is my code for create Sales order. I am using Acumatica 4.0

```
void genSO(string outletCD,string salesmanCD)
{
            Customer cus =
                PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.acctCD, Equal<Required<Customer.acctCD>>>>
                    .Select(this, outletCD);

            SalesPerson salesman=
                PXSelect<SalesPerson, Where<SalesPerson.salesPersonCD, Equal<Required<SalesPerson.salesPersonCD>>>>
                    .Select(this, salesmanCD);


            if (cus != null && cus.BAccountID != null )
            {

                SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
                SOOrder newOrder = graph.Document.Insert();
                newOrder.OrderType = "SO";
                newOrder.OrderDate=DateTime.Now;
                newOrder.RequestDate = DateTime.Now;
                newOrder.CustomerID = cus.BAccountID;

                graph.Document.Cache.RaiseFieldUpdated<SOOrder.customerID>(newOrder, null);
                newOrder.SalesPersonID = smNPP.SalesPersonID;
                graph.Document.Cache.RaiseFieldUpdated<SOOrder.salesPersonID>(newOrder, null);


                newOrder.Status = "N";
                graph.Document.Current = newOrder;

                graph.Document.Cache.Update(newOrder);
                graph.Actions.PressSave();
            }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Or it's simply doing nothing?

Comment: No It is not. But data cannot insert into database

Comment: I can spot a few problems with this code, however it works correctly in 4.2 and an order is inserted. First of all, you should replace DateTime.Now by DateTime.Today.

Comment: I replaced but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
SOOrder newOrder = (SOOrder)graph.Document.Cache.CreateInstance();
//Fill only keys.
newOrder.OrderType = "SO";    
newOrder = sograph.Document.Insert(newOrder);
//Apply automation step.
newOrder = PXCache<SOOrder>.CreateCopy(graph.Document.Search<SOOrder.orderNbr>(newOrder.OrderNbr));
newOrder.OrderDate=DateTime.Now;
newOrder.RequestDate = DateTime.Now;
newOrder.CustomerID = cus.BAccountID;
newOrder.SalesPersonID = smNPP.SalesPersonID;
graph.Document.Update(newOrder);
graph.Actions.PressSave();
```

Comment: I tried this but still nothing happens. When I debug I found the OrderNbr for new order but after that, nothing is inserted into database.

Comment: Do you have a customization for Sales Order ?

Comment: Yes, I did customization on sales order screen by add new field for    SOLine

Comment: Is it possible to unpublish it and check ?

Comment: I also did it, but still the same :(

Comment: Please remove last line PressSave() and add redirect to new created sales order using this code: throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, ""); It should open screen with your new sales order. Try to save it. Is it work?

Comment: One other piece of info - Dang is using Acumatica 4.0. Above code is what I suggested to Dang over Skype and I confirmed it works on my side (even his original version *does* insert order on my side, at least with 4.2).

Comment: Important - don't put DateTime.Now in date fields; otherwise you'll end up with time in fields which were not meant to store time. Use DateTime.Today, or let system default it :)

Comment: @Ken: yes when you open new window and save, everything is fine.

Comment: @Gabriel: as I told you, I have try many ways, but It still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

graph.Document.Insert(newOrder);
graph.Persist();

Comment: How is this supposed to resolve the problem? Also note that Actions.PressSave() is the recommended way to save, and not Psrsist()

Comment: I agree PressSave is the better option.  But it seems the OP had some difficulty with that approach.  I had a similar issue when working with CRM case activities.  I was forced to call Persist method.  Then called Refresh on the activities primary view, so that I could see the new activity that was saved.